# Replace certain lines and columns with a value of a variable

Tags: vim, awk

I am having a problem to find a solution to my following problem:
The top of my text file looks like this

```
XXXXX
XXXXXX XXXXXXX
X
X
X
XX
X
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXE+00
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXE+00
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXE+00
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXE+00
```

The Xs are random numbers. And this pattern starting on the 16th line (shown by vim as 16th line) continues until the end of the file (line 71 according to vim). The lines always start with a space bar, followed by a number and between two numbers are two space bars.
I have a variable v with the value like for example v=1.50
I want to replace the first 4 Xs of the last column by the value of the variable v for all lines from line 16 to 71, that means I want to have exactly this file at the end (space at beginning of the lines should remain):

```
XXXXX
XXXXXX XXXXXXX
X
X
X
XX
X
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00  1.50XXE+00
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00  1.50XXE+00
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00  1.50XXE+00
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00  1.50XXE+00
```

I tried a bit with awk, but I had the problem that it adds spaces between the numbers (like 1 . 5 0 ) and also I could not paste it into the correct columns and lines (vim shows "binary" columns) and I could not find the correct column with awk.
How would I do that? I want to do it for many files using a script.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is there any reason that `:%s/X\{6}E+00$/1.50XXE+00` doesn't work? Or do you want it to use some variable?

Comment: Hi, yes, the 1.50 was just an example. I also have many files, so I cannot enter vim for each file and want to do it automatically from a bash script for each file. And I forgot to write the Xs are random different numbers, so I do not know what stands there before.

Comment: When you say you have a *variable*, what do you mean?  A shell variable?  A variable inside some program?  What is its data type?

Comment: wrt `I tried a bit with awk, but I had the problem that it adds spaces between the numbers (like 1 . 5 0 )` - I can't imagine what awk code you wrote that did that but if you'd like help debugging it then post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here `sed` might be better alternative

```
$ var="1.50"; sed -E '8,$s/ ....(\S+)$/ '"$var"'\1/' file

XXXXX
XXXXXX XXXXXXX
X
X
X
XX
X
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00 1.50XXE+00
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00 1.50XXE+00
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00 1.50XXE+00
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00 1.50XXE+00
```

in your example the replacement lines start at line 8.  Change according to your actual data.

You can have the length of the variable as a derived value as well

```
$ var="1.50"; len=${#var}; sed -E '8,$s/ .{'$len'}(\S+)$/  '$var'\1/' file
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, that looks nice! If I have a variable with the value v=1.50, would I just need to use "sed -E '8,$s/(.*) ....(\S+)$/\1$v\2/' file" instead?

Comment: check the updated version.  For inserting $v inside the script you have to change single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: Thanks, it does exactly what I want. Two more things: I tried to use sed -i instead of -E to directly write the changes into the file, but it seems like this does not work? And if the file has the name "adffa.d23-24_3334_+4.33_-3.42_-5555_1.50.pfadf", with which bash command can I extract the 1.50 (or the last 4 characters before the file ending) and save it into a variable?

Comment: you need to keep `-E` for the regex group reference.  You can additionally have `-i`. For extracting the value from file name post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Just use awk for simplicity, clarity, robustness, portability, extensibility, etc...:

```
awk -v v='1.50' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="  "} NR>15{sub(/.{4}/,v,$NF)} 1' file
```

e.g. with your posted sample input:

```
$ awk -v v='1.50' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="  "} NR>7{sub(/.{4}/,v,$NF)} 1' file
XXXXX
XXXXXX XXXXXXX
X
X
X
XX
X
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00  1.50XXE+00
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00  1.50XXE+00
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00  1.50XXE+00
 XXXXXXE+00  XXXXXXEE+03  XXXXXXE+07  XXXXXXE+00  1.50XXE+00
```